# create dynamic columns in pyspark basis inputs and conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

[image: Dataframes]

I have dataframe1 (see image) and dataframe2 (see image) and the inputs are dynamic for dataframe1.
I have to create a final dataframe, considering the dynamic nature of dataframe-1 and seeing its mapping to the columns of dataframe-2.

Output1: Final dataframe which will have column names only after mapping both the dataframes basis the given condition.

Comment: how is `Dataframe1` being used? it looks like we could collect all non-null values from Dataframe2 (and their corresponding row, column) and make these the columns of the final dataframe

Comment: dataframe1 is used to fill the data in the respective columns of final dataframe.

Comment: but I couldn't I create the final dataframe with only `Dataframe2` ? what happens if Dataframe2 has a marked row that isn't in Dataframe1?